# Lightning Data Table and Click To Dial

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

We have a lightning data table(lightning:datatable) and it renders records with few phone fields with type set to 'phone'. The org has third party CTI adapter installed. The click to dial doesn't work with lightning:datatable.

[image]

When the corresponding record is open then I can see click to dial option infront of phone fields. Does anyone know why lightning:datatable doesn't show click to dial option.

Are there any workarounds to make lightning datatable work with click to dial (we really don't want to give away all the functionality that lightning data table gives)
Below is the screenshot from record detail with click to dial

[image]

Comment: You should be able to dial a number from datatable, did you try to click the phone number link from datatable?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work or to be precise it open up a facetime app instead of doing a call through CTI adapter.

Comment: If this is resolved.Please put the solution. How can we achieve click to dial from lightning datable, if we are using third party CTI

Comment: @user112796 This is not resolved. The only option you have is to build your own data-table component and explicitly use <lightning:clickToDial> for phone columns.